# Maintaining a growing list functionally

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm writing this application (while learning scala and functional programing) that has a growing list that needs to be accessed. I have a way of implementing it but it doesn't seem like a good way of doing it.

I have a class that in another thread polls another source and appends the response to a list. There is another function that will once in a while use the latest response from that list and append to another list.

The only way Ive been able to come up with is having the polling function mutate the list. I do something like declaring it when the class is created. Either by `var stream = Stream()` or `val list = collection.mutable.list`. Then have the polling function update that with `var stream = stream :+ response`.

This doesn't seem like a good way of doing this?

```
case class example extends Runnable {
  var responses = Stream[response] = Stream()
  var validResponses = Stream[response] = Stream()

  def run() {
    while(true){
      val r = pollFunction
      responses = responses :+ r
      Thread.sleep(time)
    }
  }
  def get: response = {
    lazy val r = responses.last
    if( isValid(r) ) validResponses = validResponses :+ r
    validResponses.last
  }
}
```

I just happened to use stream but that can be replaced with collection.mutable or something. Im not sure if there is a way to do something like this within a more functional way?

Comment: "I have a class that in another thread polls another source and appends the response to a list. There is another function that will once in a while use the latest response from that list and append to another list." Why do you keep a list of items? Who else uses the list? (my immediate thought is you should be sending messages from one to another, not sharing a data structure, but there's not enough detail about your usecase yet)

Comment: This class would be like a cacheing/buffer layer between a service that always needs a quick response, that doesn't necessarily need to be up to date, and server that has the data. The list would hold all the responses if you need to compare with other responses.

Comment: Then I think mutability is fine, since you do really have a stateful/mutable item (the list of responses). It's all hidden inside the one class.

Comment: you should maybe give a try to akka, that seems like a perfect solution to your use case

Comment: It sounds like you may want a (concurrent) queue, rather than a list.